# An inequality with absolute value and a parameter: $|x-4|>a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

> Solve : $|x-4|>a$.
> Case 1: $a>0$; Case 2: $a<0$

#### Progress

I am getting answers which look similar in both cases:

- Let $a>0$ so $x>4+a$ or $x<4-a$ ,
- Let $a<0$ so $x>4+a$ or $x<4-a$ .

Though I know that both answers' meaning is different I am unable to find out how the points included in both cases are different

I wish to know why it is so and how different both answers are when plotted on a number line.

Comment: can u show your work?

Comment: let a>0 so x>4+a or x<4-a , let a<0 so x>4+a or x<4-a .Though i know that both answer's meaning is different i am unable to find out how the points included in both cases are different

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152869/absolute-value-of-a-real-number

Answer (score 1):

If $a \lt 0$, all $x$ will satisfy it as all absolute values are $ \ge 0$.  If $a \gt 0$ you need the points more than $a$ from $4$.

Comment: :i was having problem to solve:|x-2|+|x-5|=3 . I was trying to post this question but could not(i was being said that it does not meet our quality standards).So posted it here.

Comment: @meg_1997:  when you have two absolute value signs, it is easiest to consider each region of $x$ and resolve the signs.  So for $x\le 2$ both expressions are negative and need to be inverted.  You are left with $7-2x=3$ AND $x \le 2$.  You solve the equality and see if it meets the inequality.  Then there are two more sections of the real line to consider the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Consider multiple cases

**Case 1**: $a = 0$

Then, any number other than $4$ will satisfy your inequality.

**Case 2**: $a < 0$

Then, any $x$ will satisfy your inequality since absolute values are $\ge 0$

**Case 3**: $a > 0$

Then $|x - 4| > a$ if and only if $x$ is farther than $a$ units from $4$.  Hence,
$x - 4 > a$ or $x - 4 < -a$.  So the set of all real numbers that satisfy your inequality is 
$$(-\infty, 4 - a) \cup (4+a, \infty)$$